# Not scrolling to the start of a list on 'next page' with a horizontal style list

Tags: html, reactjs

I have a list displayed in a div that you can scroll through and view 5 tables. They are aligned horizontally left and to the right of each other.

Once you reach the last table, you see a 'next' arrow. This are is part of the paging to fetch the next 5 elements from a mongo DB.

Example setup:

```
<div className="previousOrderWrapper">
   {this.prevPage()}
   {tables}
   {this.nextPage()}
</div>
```

nextPage ():

```
nextPage = () => {
    var newPage = this.state.pageNumber;
    newPage++;
    if (this.state.previousOrders.length < 5) {
        return (
            <div className="nextBtn">
                <button className="shaded"> <img src={arrow}/></button>
            </div>
        )
    } else {
        return (
            <div className="nextBtn">
                <button onClick={(e)=>{this.fetchData(newPage)}}><img src={arrow}/></button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

fetchData() :

```
fetchData = (newPage) => {
    axios.get('/api/orders/' + this.props.customer.name + '/' + this.props.customer.phone + '/' + newPage * 5)
    .then((res) => {
        this.setState({
            previousOrders : res.data,
            pageNumber : newPage,
        });
    }) 
}
```

fetchData does a API call for the next batch of data. What happens is the `tables` data in the previousOrderWrapper changes, but the horizontal scroll bar is still at the end of the list where it should scroll to the far left when the new data is loaded.

Here is a picture to better describe the problem:
[image: scroll bar problem]

(click next, content reload's, but scroll bar is still at the end. Need to scroll to far left on 'next')

I've tried things like [react-scrollchor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scrollchor) or with a `this.myRef` but I can't get anything to work.

How would I force the wrapper to scroll to the left with a onClick under the nextPage()?

Comment: Not totally sure what your problem is, but this is not the way to interact with state in React.  `var newPage = this.state.pageNumber; newPage++;`  Use the state directly and use `setState` to update it.  You might want to add your `fetchData` function to this question too.

Comment: I change the state of the pageNumber in fetchData, hopefully my changes to the question add clarification